# Error Code: 1845. ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported for this operation. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE

Tags: mysql, alter-table, mysql-8.0

I upgraded to MySQL 8.0.13 and tried to add a new field using ' ALGORITHM=INSTANT ' but got the following error 
" Error Code: 1845. ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported for this operation. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE "

Then I recreated the same table in MySQL 8.0.13 and tried to add the same field using ' ALGORITHM=INSTANT ' and it works!

Will this new feature of MySQL (ALGORITHM=INSTANT) only works on newly created tables in the upgraded version?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, this is a bug

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92194

which is explaining " For ALTER TABLE, ALGORITHM=INSTANT was incorrectly rejected on tables created in a MySQL version prior to 8.0.12 " " Fixed in 8.0.14. "

I didn't tested it with 8.0.14. I will post here the results once I tested it with 8.0.14.